# Getting REST xml from DTO class

Tags: java, rest

I am doing some REST web service work and a lot of the PUTS are taking DTO classes. Some of these classes are quite large. Is there something I can use to get the XML representation for these classes? I am finding it quite time consuming to go through the DTOs and try and work out the XML structure. I inevitably get it wrong a few times so it becomes time consuming.

Is there a way I can get XML representation of a standard bean class in Java?

Thanks

Comment: i'm confused as to what you are specifically looking for?  jaxb will convert the annotated beans to xml for you...?

Comment: I want to be able to test my web service calls. i am using RestClient and do am constructing the xml so then post to my webservice to check it reads them correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is where jaxb annotations are handy:

To get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<car registration="abc123">
  <brand>Volvo</brand>
  <description>Sedan</description>
</car>
```

From this:

```
public class Car {
  private String registration;
  private String brand;
  private String description;
}
```

Use these annotations:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder = {"brand", "description"})
public class Car {
  private String registration;
  private String brand;
  private String description;

  @XmlAttribute
  public String getRegistration() {
      return registration;
  }

  public String getBrand() {
      return brand;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
      return description;
  }
```

}

Note: I've removed setters/constructors for brevity.

Sourced from http://thomassundberg.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/how-to-convert-a-pojo-to-xml-with-jaxb/, which is an excellent starting point.

Comment: Hi Anew, thanks for the answer but it is the other way I want. If I have the java class with annotations is there an easy way to get the xml? If have classes which contain other classes so the xml gets quite complicated. Thanks

Comment: JAXB is bi-directional. It will produce classes from XML (unmarshall); and XML from classes (marshall). Look for examples with `JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz); context.createMarshaller(); context.createUnmarshaller();` Having nested classes is also supported.

Comment: +1 - @RNJ, JAXB is configuration by exception so you only need to add annotations where you want to override the default XML representation:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Comment: understood. Thanks for the code for marshalling and unmarshalling. Very useful!